# How to make a ajax call with csrf and body?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, forms, api

I have build a login api with django. I used postman to check its function.
The request body is

```
{"user":{"email":"surendersingh1995nov@gmail.com", "password":"Singo*1995"}}
```

The request url is

```
 POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/login/
```

The header is content-type

```
application/json
```

The response is

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "surendersingh1995nov@gmail.com",
        "username": "ArjunSingh",
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6MSwiZXhwIjoxNjAwMjM3MjcxfQ.OBF3tg2YmXC4hl4D7eTfx38rrXX9RKGwIQBqKorwqOw"
    }
}
```

This is the way I would like to get the response in ajax call.The API works good in Postman. But if I try to make the same request through AJAX I get 400 Bad request
error.

The AJAX call I made

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/api/users/login/?",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:{"user":{"email":"surendersingh1995nov@gmail.com", "password":"Singo*1995"}},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log("error")
              console.log(data.statusText)
              console.log(data.status)
            }
          })
```

Comment: use JSON.stringify in data :JSON.stringify( {"user":{"email":"sur....